# tentado extrair diferentes dados de um ficheiro txt

Tags: java

O ficheiro contem o 1º número que indica quantas matrizes serão criadas e a seguir dois números separados que indicam a ordem da matriz e depois as strings que serão transformadas em uma série de caracteres e os dados no ficheiro são apresentados da seguinte forma:

```
2

2 3 
abc
bcd

3 4
abcd
vbnm
jklo
```

e o resultado final tem de ser:

```
matriz 1:
a b c
b c d

matriz 2:
a b c d
v b n m
j k l o
```

esse é o meu código:

```
public static void lerFC() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    
    File file = new File("ggf.txt");
    BufferedReader lerFC = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ggf.txt"));
    String linha;
    ArrayList<CacPalavras> cacPalavras = new ArrayList();
    
    
        while((linha = lerFC.readLine()) != null) {
            
            int m, n;
            String m_n[] = linha.split(" ");
            m = Integer.parseInt(m_n[0]); 
            n = Integer.parseInt(m_n[1]);
            CacPalavras novaCac = new CacPalavras();
            
            if(linha.split(" ").length > 1){
            
                novaCac.m = m;
                novaCac.n = n;
                char[][] matriz = new char[n][m];
                
                
            }else{
                if(linha.length()== m){
                    String[] aux = new String[m];
                    char[][] matriz = new char[n][m];
                    
                    for(int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++){
                        aux[i] = linha;
                        matriz[i] = aux[i].toCharArray();
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }cacPalavras.add(novaCac);
            
        }lerFC.close();
        
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Acho que o jeito mais fácil é usando o `Scanner`. Olha só como poderia ficar:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    char[][][] matrixArray = createMatrixArray("ggf.txt");

    for (char[][] cs : matrixArray) {
      printMatrix(cs);
    }
  }

  private static void printMatrix(char[][] matrix) {
    int rowCount = matrix.length;
    int colCount = matrix[0].length;

    System.out.printf("Matriz de %d x %d\n", rowCount, colCount);

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[row]));
    }
  }

  private static char[][][] createMatrixArray(String path) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(Files.newInputStream(Path.of(path)))) {
      int matrixCount = scan.nextInt();

      char[][][] matrixArray = new char[matrixCount][][];

      for (int i = 0; i < matrixCount; i++) {
        int rowsCount = scan.nextInt();
        int colsCount = scan.nextInt();

        matrixArray[i] = new char[rowsCount][colsCount];

        for (int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++) {
          char[] chars = scan.next().toCharArray();

          for (int col = 0; col < colsCount; col++) {
            matrixArray[i][row][col] = chars[col];
          }
        }
      }

      return matrixArray;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      return new char[0][][];
    }
  }
}
```